# Adding multiple Composer packages

Tags: composer-php

I'm using Composer to install multiple packages using the following syntax:

```json
{
    "require": {
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "2.*",
        "vimeo/vimeo-api": "1.1.*",
        "phpoffice/phpexcel": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

The above works just fine, but now I'd like to add tcpdf via composer.  I found this code [here](https://github.com/tcpdf-clone/tcpdf/blob/master/composer.json) but am not sure how to integrate with my current requires.  One thing that I tried was to just add it to the end, but I fear that it started deleting my current packages.

```json
{
    "name": "tecnick.com/tcpdf",
    "version": "6.2.11",
    "homepage": "http://www.tcpdf.org/",
    "type": "library",
    "description": "TCPDF is a PHP class for generating PDF documents and barcodes.",
    "keywords": [
        "PDF",
        "tcpdf",
        "PDFD32000-2008",
        "qrcode",
        "datamatrix",
        "pdf417",
        "barcodes"
    ],
    "license": "LGPLv3",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Nicola Asuni",
            "email": "info@tecnick.com",
            "homepage": "http://nicolaasuni.tecnick.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "fonts",
            "config",
            "include",
            "tcpdf.php",
            "tcpdf_parser.php",
            "tcpdf_import.php",
            "tcpdf_barcodes_1d.php",
            "tcpdf_barcodes_2d.php",
            "include/tcpdf_colors.php",
            "include/tcpdf_filters.php",
            "include/tcpdf_font_data.php",
            "include/tcpdf_fonts.php",
            "include/tcpdf_images.php",
            "include/tcpdf_static.php",
            "include/barcodes/datamatrix.php",
            "include/barcodes/pdf417.php",
            "include/barcodes/qrcode.php"
        ]
    }
```

Comment: What **exactly** have you tried? Why not install tcpdf like all other packages?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To add "tecnick.com/tcpdf" to an existing `composer.json` file, on the commandline inside the directory containing it run:

```
composer require tecnick.com/tcpdf
```

You shouldn't have to manually edit the composer.json file for such things.

Comment: Thanks for the tip; I never new that I could add the package from the commandline.  Would you know why the author would provide the additional json above?  Is this something that I could "see" using the commandline as well?

Comment: The author didn't provide that additional json for your consumption. First of all, you linked to a clone repository, not the original repository. Second, every package you want to install with Composer must have some metadata for Composer to work, and that is in this file. It is for TCPDF only - the only useful information in there is the "name" field because that is what you have to install if you want to use that package. Another way to find out about that name is to go to https://packagist.org and search for the library. You usually find links to the lib homepage and repository there.

Comment: Makes perfect sense; I hadn't realized that most of the json had served a different purpose.

Answer (score 49):

You can require many packages from the command line, for example:

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-debugbar barryvdh/laravel-snappy fideloper/proxy
```

And all the packages will be required according to your composer specifications.

Answer (score 20):

As a matter of fact, you can list all the packages separated by space, like so:

```
composer require aws/aws-sdk-php vimeo/vimeo-api phpoffice/phpexcel
```

Quote:

> If you do not want to choose requirements interactively, you can pass
>   them to the command

From [Composer documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require)

Also consider `--update-with-all-dependencies` to update the dependencies of all newly installed packages.

Comment: I was trying to update phpunit/phpunit ^8, and composer just gave me `Conclusion: don't install sebastian/object-enumerator 3.0.3`
With `--update-with-all-dependencies` it worked nicely. I thought composer is doing this automatically if you *require* a package.

Answer (score 13):

If anyone else comes here and wants to know how to add "multiple" packages, simply use the [Composer require command](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require) and run multiple CLI commands by terminating them with a semi-colon, e.g.

```
composer require drupal/pathauto;
composer require 'drupal/google_analytics:^3.0';
composer require 'doctrine/doctrine-bundle:2.*';
composer require 'monolog/monolog:~2.0.0';
```

Alternatively run with the `--no-update` flag to disable automatic update of dependencies and run all the updates together — composer will resolve dependencies in one hit:

```
composer require drupal/pathauto --no-update;
composer require 'drupal/google_analytics:^3.0' --no-update;
composer require 'doctrine/doctrine-bundle:2.*' --no-update;
composer require 'monolog/monolog:~2.0.0' --no-update;
composer update;
```

If you don't specify a version then composer will automatically pull the latest release. It's worth reading up on [Composer versions and constraints](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md), especially when it comes to updating packages. Check the  [Composer require command](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require) for more useful flags.

It can be useful to keep package requirements on separate lines as above, e.g. if you have a reference document of regularly installed packages, or if the commands are being generated by a build tool.

Alternatively you can run them all on one line:

```
composer require drupal/pathauto 'drupal/google_analytics:^3.0' 'doctrine/doctrine-bundle:2.*' 'monolog/monolog:~2.0.0';
```

---

N.B. Terminating commands with a semi-colon is a general solution for running multiple CLI commands, and not just composer specific, e.g.

```
composer self-update;
composer require 'drupal/google_analytics:^3.0';
cd app/build;
yarn run build;
```

Comment: As provided in the documentation: simply list all packages to be required in one call, that's much easier and faster than running multiple ones

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add handful of packages without having to wait tediously for composer to update after each and every one, but you prefer not to:

- change a long series of modules together in a single line (poor readability, less convenient to reuse)
- use a semi-colon delimited list of commands ([featherbelly's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48323800/763419) - easy to insert a typo or accidentally paste a carriage return and screw it up midway through)

…then use the `--no-update` switch to have composer modify the `composer.json` file ONLY, without searching for packages.

You can run as few or as many as you want, use the CLI to do something else midway through, and when you're ready, just do `composer-update` by itself.

Here's an example of adding some Drupal modules for a new project:

```
composer require 'drupal/field_permissions:^1.0' --no-update
composer require 'drupal/coffee:^1.0' --no-update
composer require 'drupal/token:^1.5' --no-update
composer require 'drupal/field_tools:^1.0' --no-update
composer require 'drupal/required_by_role:^1.0' --no-update
composer require 'drupal/devel:^2.1' --no-update
composer require 'drupal/config_ignore:^2.1' --no-update
composer require 'drupal/ga_login:^1.0' --no-update
composer require 'drupal/tfa:^1.0' --no-update
composer require 'drupal/spambot:^1.0' --no-update
composer require 'drupal/pathauto:^1.4' --no-update
composer require 'drupal/flag:^4.0' --no-update
composer require 'drupal/stringoverrides:1.x-dev' --no-update
composer require 'drupal/structure_sync:^1.16' --no-update
composer require 'drupal/masquerade:^2.0' --no-update
composer require 'drupal/metatag:^1.8' --no-update
composer require 'drupal/unique_field_ajax:^1.2' --no-update
composer require 'drupal/config_override_warn:^1.2' --no-update
composer require 'drupal/environment_indicator:^3.6' --no-update
composer require 'drupal/role_delegation:^1.0' --no-update
composer require 'drupal/seo_checklist:^4.1' --no-update

composer update
```

NB: If you know what the modules you need **and are typing your list manually anyway**, just edit `composer.json` by hand - there's no point manually typing "composer require" over and over again.

*However*, the above method is handy for sites like Drupal where you're copying and pasting pre-written commands that contain complex version syntax for branches, individual commits etc.